# Vaadin 14 excessive browser polling

Tags: websocket, vaadin-flow

From the moment a brower is connected to a Vaadin 14 application, it spawns dozens of request per second.
Example:
GET /lbsm-webapp/index/?v-r=push&v-uiId=3&v-pushId=d06832fa-5fc0-478b-be1a-b7201c6e9017&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=86035393-8490-48bc-8d3c-b5c6e08ee235&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.2.vaadin1-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=long-polling&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application%2Fjson%3B%20charset%3DUTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true&X-Vaadin-LastSeenServerSyncId=6582&_=1693234167142 HTTP/1.1
Host: host1.mycompany.be
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/116.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://client.mycompany.be/lbsm-webapp/index/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=rrH0kfdofofds******************

Is there a way to limit the rate of these requests ?
Long polling is used automatically by the javascript client since websockets are not supported by the sever(Jboss 7.x). Thanks for any help.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem, it seems to be embedded in the Atmosphere framework.

Comment: Which exact Vaadin 14 version is this?

Comment: Looks like there's something that continuously introduces changes to the UI, so the HTTP push connection is flushed and closed at every request.
Do you have background threads that frequently update the UI?
You can try to set the logger for `com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.UIInternals` to TRACE level to check when the server sync Id is updated, meaning that UI changes will be sent to the client

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same issue - Vaadin 14.10.4.  A WAF or a load balancer can technically block these requests by matching the URL, but UI updates will stop.   I can provide more information to Vaadin as I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your descriptions fit to the bug that has been fixed in Vaadin 14.10.8 and newer versions. See more:

https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/17238